# is there any other way to stop the node js program other than process.exit() in node js programming

Tags: node.js

I am looping through the JSON array and based on the condition it should come out of the program. But process.exit() is not recommended for my case, is there any other solution?

Comment: Show me, how you are looping the JSON array

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: for(var item in obj)
{
 if(item.date < cuttOffDate)
 {
  my stuff 
 }
}

Here I have a set of jsons in JSON array , when item.date is less than cutoff date then I want to exit from program but as I need to loop through array oj jsons it won't